# Returning a 2D array from c function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm a python programmer writing some c (wrapped in ctypes) to speed up some tight loops.  I'm having trouble with a function that takes a two dimensional array `(*double)[2]`, does some things to it and returns it.  Function looks something like the following:

```
double *process(int n, double (*results)[2], ...) {
    // Do some things to results
    return results;
}
```

Here, n is the number of elements in the first level of results.  This doesn't compile, apparently I'm returning from an incompatible pointer type.  Making it `return *results` allows it to compile and run (all the contained logic is fine), but segfaults at the return.  Making the function a `double **` and returning with any number of `*`s doesn't let me compile.

Clearly I'm being an idiot here, which isn't surprising at all as I don't really understand c pointers.  What do I need to do to make this work?  I've got another function that returns a `double *` working fine, so it's clearly something to do with the 2D array.

Comment: double (*results)[2] is meant to receive 2D array here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get new `results` you even don't need to return anything. The array is passed by address, not values.

```
void process(int n, double results[][2], ...) {
    // Do some things to results,
    results[n][0] = 1.0l;
    // And no need to return.
}
int main(){
    double array[2][2] = { .0 };
    printf( "Before process: %lf", array[1][0] );
    process( 1, array );
    printf( "After process: %lf", array[1][0] );
}
```

It should output:

```
Before process: 0.0000000000
After process: 1.0000000000
```

Comment: This makes some degree of sense, I think I've still got problems with ctypes here and not the c

Answer (score 0):

to return 2D array you need to use

```
double **
```

To take a 2D array as parameter in function process() you can use

```
double *results[2]
```

or

```
double results[2][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function's return value expects only a `1D array` as return value. to make it work with 2D arrays, make it `double **`.

when you're returning, return only `results`. don't put any `*` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
double ** process(int n, double ** results)
{
    /* Do stuffz */
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to return a pointer to a two dimension array. In this case you would have to use:

```
double (*process (int n, double results[][2], ...))[2] {
  return results;
}
```

This basically means "return a pointer to two 2 elements of double"

Or, to make it somehow more readable:

```
typedef double arrayType[2];

arrayType * process(int n, double results[][2]) {
    return results;
}
```